# SQS - Get Message By Id

Tags: amazon-sqs

Is it possible for me to get a message from the SQS queue based on the message ID with the Amazon PHP SDK? Do I have to just grab all of the messages on the queue and then filter it on my server?

My server receives a SNS instigated request with a queue message Id and I'm having to filter the message from an array of messages from SQS.

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of a queue is to use it as a buffer to store messages before a certain processing task. This should not be confused with a storage service or a database service. Amazon SQS allows a process to retrieve messages from a queue (buffer) and process them as needed. If needed `Standard` or `FIFO` queues can be used.

In answer to your question: SQS does not provide a mechanism to retrieve by `Message ID`. So as you suggested, you can have separate workers to retrieve all messages in parallel and look for the message with the ID you want. (This can be exhaustive)

Since your use case is similar to that of a storage service, I suggest writing to a storage service and retrieving from it based on a column named "Message ID".

Answer (score 2):

Just so that it may help someone else. I couldn't find a straight forward method to do this. Instead, implementing another set of queue workers to delegate the tasks solved the performance issue. These workers performed only two tasks

1. Retrieve queue item
2. Associative valid id
3. Send it to the processing server (after performing load checks, availability etc)

Answer (score -1):

I would have to know more about your use case to know, but it sounds like you are using SQS as a database.   Might I recommend instead of sending messages to SQS and sending the message ID to SNS, instead adding a row in DynamoDB, and sending to key through SNS?

Or even better yet, just send the raw data through SNS?

Comment: Yes, my use case is very similar to that of a database. Would sending the message ID to SNS help in any way? I wouldn't be able to retrieve one at a time. DynamoDB would be a much better service to use, I agree.

Comment: @A23, no, sending the message ID to SNS will not help.  There is no capability in SQS to retrieve messages based on message ID.