# Get particular message from Amazon SQS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-sqs

Is there any way to retrieve message by some id. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544358/sqs-get-message-by-id) it is written that it's not possible. But as the answer is old so I am asking again if it's still the same or not.

I am sending message in the below way --

```
const params = {
      DelaySeconds: 0,
      MessageAttributes: {
        test: {
          DataType: 'String',
          StringValue: 'bdbdh',
        },
      },
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify({
        AccountId: '100'
      }),
      QueueUrl: 'url',
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('data', err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('data', data);
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

Retrieving the message in the below way --

```
const params = {
      MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
      MessageAttributeNames: ["test"],
      VisibilityTimeout: 600,
      QueueUrl: 'url',
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('data', err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('data', data);
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

I has also tried to get the messages by attribute name,but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible to retrieve a specific message from an Amazon SQS queue. You can call `ReceiveMessage()` to get 1 to 10 messages, but you cannot choose which messages to receive.

You can add *message attributes* to a message (eg priority, customer number) but they can't be used to retrieve a specific or subset of messages.

In general, messages come back in order but this is not guaranteed. For example, a message that was invisible and then made visible again will be out-of-order. Also, message order is impacted by the distributed nature of the servers used by Amazon SQS.

See: [Amazon SQS short and long polling - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html)

Message order is guaranteed for a first-in-first-out (FIFO) queue, but it cannot let you access a specific message.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to pull from sqs by id.

Per SQS documentation there is no parameter that you can pass:

```
var params = {
  QueueUrl: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  AttributeNames: [
    All | Policy | VisibilityTimeout | MaximumMessageSize | MessageRetentionPeriod | ApproximateNumberOfMessages | ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible | CreatedTimestamp | LastModifiedTimestamp | QueueArn | ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed | DelaySeconds | ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds | RedrivePolicy | FifoQueue | ContentBasedDeduplication | KmsMasterKeyId | KmsDataKeyReusePeriodSeconds,
    /* more items */
  ],
  MaxNumberOfMessages: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  MessageAttributeNames: [
    'STRING_VALUE',
    /* more items */
  ],
  ReceiveRequestAttemptId: 'STRING_VALUE',
  VisibilityTimeout: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  WaitTimeSeconds: 'NUMBER_VALUE'
};
sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

[AWS SQS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#receiveMessage-property)